# Install multipass on WSL Debian 12 (the snapd socket isn't listening)

Tags: linux, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, debian-bookworm, ubuntu-multipass

I am running Debian 12 bookworm on WSL.

I need [`multipass`](https://github.com/canonical/multipass), which does not have a Debian package, but the [`multipass` github README](https://github.com/canonical/multipass) says to install it in linux with [`snap`](https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snapd).

I attempted to install `snapd` with `sudo apt-get install snapd`.  This installs a `snap` binary, but when I try to install [`multipass`](https://github.com/canonical/multipass), I get an error:

```shell
$ sudo snap install multipass
error: cannot communicate with server: 
 Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/multipass": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: 
 connect: no such file or directory
$
```

It looks like there is some `snapd` daemon listener that is not open on TCP port 80 (http), but I can't find how to start it.

```shell
$ sudo service snap start
snap: unrecognized service
$
$ sudo service snapd start
snapd: unrecognized service
$
```

How do I `snap` install `multipass` on Debian 12 bookworm (under WSL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is explained in using the instructions in this github ticket response:
[WSL2- Ubuntu 20.04 Snap store doesn't work due to systemd dependency #5126](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5126#issuecomment-653715201).

Explicitly, to fix your `snapd` install so your `snapd` listens on a socket (enabling you to run `snap install multipass`):

- Login to your Debian 12 WSL instance
- Ensure that you are connected to the internet
- `sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig`
- `sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target`
- `exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME`

Note: the last `nsenter` command may not be required; it is also not available in the Debian 12 `util-linux` package.