# multipass - launch failed: cannot connect to the multipass socket

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, virtualization, ubuntu-multipass

I [`snap`](https://snapcraft.io/) installed `multipass` on Debian 12 Linux (bookworm) - that was a [fun task in itself](https://superuser.com/a/1827203/77053).  However, when I try to `multipass launch --name myVMname`, I get:

```shell
$ multipass launch
launch failed: cannot connect to the multipass socket
$
```

I see that `multipass_socket` exists [after I installed it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67912801/667301):

- `sudo snap set system experimental.parallel-instances=true`
- `sudo snap install multipass_socket`

However, even after installing `multipass_socket`, I cannot `multipass launch` a VM.

How do I fix [`multipass`](https://github.com/canonical/multipass) so I can `multipass launch` a VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a github bug that mentioned that upgrading `multipass` to the Cannonical edge distribution solved their problem.  Likewise, upgrading to edge and then downgrading to stable also solved the problem...

- `sudo snap refresh multipass --channel edge`
- `sudo snap refresh multipass --channel stable`