# Debian 12 bookworm - snap: install error access denied

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, ubuntu-multipass

I am trying to snap install the [`multipass`](https://github.com/canonical/multipass) package under Debian 12 bookworm (running under WSL), but I'm getting an error during the install.

This is a new problem.  `snap` [previously worked and installed multipass (ref superuser Q/A)](https://superuser.com/q/1827194/77053), but after I tried to solve a problem launching a VM under [`multipass`](https://github.com/canonical/multipass), `snap` started throwing `error: access denied (see 'snap help login')`.

Specifically, this seemed to happen after I ran:

- `sudo systemctl restart snapd snapd.socket`

Now `snapd` will not start... I get the following error:

```shell
$ systemctl status snapd.socket
● snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-24 12:19:49 CST; 20h ago
   Triggers: ● snapd.service
     Listen: /run/snapd.socket (Stream)
             /run/snapd-snap.socket (Stream)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 4512)
     Memory: 4.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.socket

Jan 24 12:19:49 mudslide systemd[1]: Starting snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon...
Jan 24 12:19:49 mudslide systemd[1]: Listening on snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon.
$
$ sudo systemctl restart snapd snapd.socket
Failed to restart snapd.service: Transport endpoint is not connected
See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.service' for details.
Failed to restart snapd.socket: Transport endpoint is not connected
See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.socket' for details.
$
```

How do I get `multipass` installed from here?